# How to launch Matlab through PHP

Tags: php, matlab, terminal, localhost

How do I run a MATLAB code saved as a .m file from a php file? I am new to php and am learning along the way. I am capturing information from a website and then need to run some numbers. I need MATLAB because the calculations are quite complex but managed to connect to the same database and pull relevant values directly from MATLAB so literally all I'm trying to do is open MATLAB and run the .m file, which already has everything in the code.

I have version MATLAB 2012b and am running the website on my localhost using MAMP.

So far I've tried this:

`<?php system('/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r "code.m"'); ?>`

Nothing happens which is strange because in Terminal if I enter the code above inside the '' the code runs perfectly.

Another thing I tried was running this:

`<?php system('cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin; ls; open matlab');?>`

The output is correct because I get:

`activate_matlab.sh, m3iregistry, mexopts.sh, deactivate_matlab.sh, maci64, mw_mpiexec, deploytool, matlab, mw_smpd, engopts.sh, matopts.sh     optsetup.sh, insttype.ini, mbuild, registry, lcdata.xml, mbuildopts.sh, util, lcdata.xsd        mcc, worker, lcdata_utf8.xml, mex, ldd, mexext`

This means I am able to access the "bin" directly where the MATLAB Unix Executable File is sitting, but I can't run the actual Unix Executable File.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the MatLab script do? Instead of using the `system()` which executes and dumps output, try capturing output putting your command in [PHP backticks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) and assigning the output to a variable and dumping it. Something like this: `<?php $output = \`/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r "code.m"\`; var_dump($output); ?>`

Comment: @LukeCordingley I get the following result: `string(0) ""`

Comment: A permissions issue maybe? Does your PHP user have execute permissions in /Applications?

Comment: @horchler It may be a permissions issue. I am able to open up folders inside the user where the Matlab license is sitting, just not execute them. When I type `whoami` in PHP I get the following result: `_www`. How can I execute the command as is I were the Matlab user, not "_www"?

Comment: I ended up compiling my code as a standalone application and reading it with Matlab Complier Runtime which is free and can be installed on any server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked this out. What I ended up doing was compile a standalone application with the MALTAB Compiler toolbox and simply have the server interpret the code by installing MATLAB Complier Runtime (MCR) on it. Please note, however, that the operating system has to be the same on the server. So if you compile in Mac and use MCR in Ubuntu it will not work. You need this to be uniform because a lot of OS-specific references are produced in the script that MCR interprets. Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you accept this answer so that the quesion isn't left hanging out there?